# Passing a variable from class module to userform

Tags: vba, pass-by-reference, userform, pass-by-value, first-class-modules

Hej,
I am trying to design a code, where a number of commandbuttons call the same userform. I have created the class module and got it to work so that they all call the userform, but I need the name of the button passed on from the class module into the userform initialize. I have tried it with property get and a public function, but can't get it to work. The variable I want to pass is the "ScreenShotCap" as string Anyone, who can help?

**CLASS MODULE CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Public ScreenShotCap As String
Public WithEvents CmdBtn As MSForms.CommandButton


Property Set obj(btns As MSForms.CommandButton)

'Defines the property of the object called
    Set CmdBtn = btns
    
End Property


Private Sub CmdBtn_Click()

'Gets the button caption
    ScreenShotCap = CmdBtn.Name

'Loads the userform
    ufScreenshot.Show
  
End Sub
```

**USERFORM CODE**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim btnNo As Variant
Dim imNo1, imNo2, imNo3 As Integer


'Gets the number of the button
    btnNo = Right(ScreenShotCap, 1)

'Sets the image number
    imNo1 = Int(btnNo + 2)
    imNo2 = Int(btnNo + 3)
    imNo3 = Int(btnNo + 4)
    
'Loads the image from MSForms into userform
    If ScreenShotCap = Worksheets("SW_TEST").OLEObjects("CommandButton1").Name Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Me.Image1.Picture = Worksheets("SW_TEST").OLEObjects("Image1").Object.Picture
            Me.Image2.Picture = Worksheets("SW_TEST").OLEObjects("Image2").Object.Picture
            Me.Image3.Picture = Worksheets("SW_TEST").OLEObjects("Image3").Object.Picture
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Me.Image1.Picture = Worksheets("SW_TEST").OLEObjects("Image" & imNo1).Object.Picture
            Me.Image2.Picture = Worksheets("SW_TEST").OLEObjects("Image" & imNo2).Object.Picture
            Me.Image3.Picture = Worksheets("SW_TEST").OLEObjects("Image" & imNo3).Object.Picture
            
        'after any change vba has to be told to refresh the UserForm for the change to appear
            Me.Repaint
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Add a hidden label to the form and set the value after the form is opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the codes in `UserForm_Initialize()` to a new sub with a parameter or just rename it to:

```
Public Sub LoadButtonImage(ScreenShotCap As String)
```

Then in your `CmdBtn_Click()` sub:

```
Load ufScreenshot.Show
ufScreenshot.LoadButtonImage CmdBtn.Name 
uScreenshot.Show
```